# Python win32com method for word-wrap in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I need to write a function that will word wrap the contents of all sheets of an active Excel workbook. I have everything written except the necessary method. I am not able to find it anywhere. Does anyone have any knowledge on this?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

def main():
    WordWrapColumns()

def WordWrapColumns():
    excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    filename = excel.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    #Activate all sheets
    active_sheets = wb.Sheets.Count
    for i in range(0,active_sheets):
        excel.Worksheets(i+1).Activate()
        # Word wrap all columns in sheet
        # What command goes here????
    #Save and close workbook
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "microsoft excel interop yourFunctionOrConstantOrClass" for web searches (works in google). In your case "microsoft excel interop word wrap" finds [Range.WrapText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.wraptext%28v=office.15%29.ASPX) which suggests you should be able to do something like

```
for i in range(0,active_sheets):
    ws = wb.Worksheets(i+1)
    ws.Columns.WrapText = True
```