# How to format the index column of excel while using dataframe to convert xls to csv Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert xls to csv using python df. However I am not able to remove the \n or whatever is present in the index col of the excel.

The input excel :

[image: Input excel]

And the output is printing the words in brackets in different lines.

The expected output is like :

[image: output csv]

The Code is :

```
  data_xls = pd.read_excel('/home/scripts/usless/HP_PO_hist.xls', 'sheet1', index_col=4,skiprows=3)
  data_xls.to_csv('HH_PO_output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

But this is scrambling the index line. How to handle this?

Comment: so you want to convert your excel to csv without any empty rows?

Comment: No, actually, the index row (first column in excel) is words like "East Central \n (SA)", East South Central \n (NSA) etc. This \n needs to be removed in the index row(first row)

Comment: And remove the empty line present perhaps :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done not by deleting `\n` but `\r\n` I'll check it out

Comment: Can you show the index of your data in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest would be to lauch you original excel with win32 , iterate through the line where you want to disable the textWrap and use

```
for i in range(0,active_sheets):
    ws = wb.Worksheets(i+1)
    ws.Columns.WrapText = false
```

you'll need to adapt these lines to get only the first line.

[Python win32com method for word-wrap in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108791/python-win32com-method-for-word-wrap-in-excel)

Comment: This is a linux server on which the script would run.